# jQuery BlockUi Message after another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, blockui

I'm using jQuery BlockUI plugin, and i have been able to sucessfully show a single message in the page, however... let's say that I want to show 3 messages , one after another.

**Something like:**

1. message: 'hello world!'
2. message: 'hello galaxy!'
3. message: 'hello universe!'

how do I do this with jQuery BlockUI?

Comment: when r u unblocking them ? is it  block "hello world" unblock "hello world" block " galaxy" unblock " galaxy" .... or  block "hello" block "galaxy" block "universe" unblock in LIFO/FIFO order ?

Comment: It's in FIFO, and it's block 'hello world'. unblock, block 'hello galaxy', unblock, block 'hello universe', unblock

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just create a div in your page like this:

```
<div id="blockMessage"></div>
```

And for the script...

```
$.blockUI({ message: $('#blockMessage') });
$("#blockMessage").html('Hello World!');
$("#blockMessage").html('Hello Galaxy!');
$("#blockMessage").html('Hello Universe!);
$.unblockUI();
```

This goes by very fast, but you get the idea....bonus here is you can style it to look however you want as well, e.g.:

```
#blockMessage { font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 3):

This does not work when you have some callback function is being called on onBlock or onUnBlock, for example like this:

**$.blockUI({
     message : 'your new message',
     onBlock : callbackFunction
  });**

An alternative to this would be, just call blockUI again with a different message:

**$.blockUI({ message: 'New message' });**