# Block UI Real time message

Tags: jquery, blockui

Please let me know how to change the blockUI message in real time, in the following scenario, without flickering or calling blockUI.

E.g.:

```
$.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Please wait - calculating Exposure </h1>' }); 
Ajax call1 CalculateExposure()
Ajax call2 CheckStatus() // Will run every 5 seconds for max 2 minutes
{ 
    // Here i want to change block ui page message to checking rates,etc... 
    // This is calling again so page is flickering...
    // $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>checking rates </h1>' });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery BlockUi Message after another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027655/jquery-blockui-message-after-another)

Comment: This is not duplicate, Question is to change message without flickering or calling block ui again ,Problem with appending message is page flickering because of re calling Block UI

Comment: Thats not appending, it does exactly what you want. It changes the text dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I give you a more exact answer, if it was not clear. Define you first message like this:

```
$.blockUI({
    message: '<h1 id="myMessage">Please wait - calculating Exposure </h1>'
});
```

Then, after you want to update your message, do this:

```
document.getElementById('myMessage').value = 'checking rates';
```

Or the jQuery way:

```
$('#myMessage').text('checking rates');
```

This will only change the text in the *existing* blockUI window!

If you have finished your long process, you can finally unblock the UI:

```
$.unblockUI();
```

Comment: This one is correct answer and other answer is partially correct(jQuery BlockUi Message after another ) but it removes page blocking